# how to display the macro in marginpar?

Tags: macros

I using oneside in book.cls. So the marginnote display on the right, I want display some macros on the left, how could I do?

**I mean the left show macros and the right show marginnote.They can be displayed in the same paragraph. Perhaps this is very strange. As show below:**

[image]

I want to achieve this function just like write the marginnote, for example: `\marginnote{something} \acommand{\cassistsupervisor}`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I do not know if that helps you, but try `\reversemarginpar` before using the notes.

Answer (score 1):

See **ADDENDUM** for revision to reflect OP's clarified question.

Here I introduce `\margcmd` that takes the macro name (without backslash) and right aligns it in the marginpar box, with a leading backslash, and using `\ttfamily`.

Manuel also makes the suggestion, using `\string`, that would allow you to include the backslash in the call itself, and [optionally] omit the braces.  I call his suggestion `\manuelcmd`

Another option, shown in the final case, is `\marginpar{\hfill\textbackslash lastmacro}`, which has been embodied in the `\acommand` macro.

```
\documentclass{article}    
\newcommand\margcmd[1]{\marginpar{\hfill\ttfamily\char'134#1‌​}}
\newcommand*\manuelcmd[1]{\marginpar{\hfill\ttfamily\string#1}‌​}
\newcommand\acommand[1]{\marginpar{\hfill\textbackslash #1}}
\reversemarginpar
\begin{document}
This is a test.\margcmd{mymacro}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
This is a test.\manuelcmd{\nextmacro}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
This is a test.\acommand{nothermacro}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ADDENDUM**

To handle both the macro names on the left margin, and other `\marginpar`s on the right margin, I resort to an alternate mechanism for setting the left-side macro names, namely the `tabto` package.  I create a macro similar to `\marginpar`, called `\mpar`, using a `tabto` approach.  Then, I am free to set actual `\marginpar` text on the right, while setting macro names on the left.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabto}   
\newcommand\mpar[1]{\leavevmode\tabto*{-1in}\makebox[.8in]{#1}%
  \tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}
\newcommand\margcmd[1]{\mpar{\hfill\ttfamily\char'134#1‌​}}
\newcommand*\manuelcmd[1]{\mpar{\hfill\ttfamily\string#1}‌​}
\newcommand\acommand[1]{\mpar{\hfill\textbackslash #1}}
\begin{document}
This\marginpar{This is my marginpar, the first} is a test. \margcmd{mymacro}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
This is a test.\manuelcmd{\nextmacro}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
This\marginpar{My last and final marginpar} is a test. \acommand{nothermacro}
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May be an alternative with `\string` that lets the user write `\margcmd\macro`, which might be preferred would be `\newcommand*\margcmd[1]{\marginpar{\hfill\ttfamily\string#1}}`.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks.  I have given your suggestion as an option, as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! But what I want is like this picture which you can see in my problem description now, by the way, pay attention to the bold font. thank you for your patience and time!

Comment: @邹思宇 Please see my **ADDENDUM**.